# Validação com if para verificar se valor é undefined

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

Estou com dificuldade para verificar se o valor é `undefinded`. Preciso fazer um `if` para essa validação, segue meu código:

Minha interface:

```
interface IModalContatos {
  dados: IContatos | undefined;
  onSave:(dados: IContatos) => void;
  onClose:() => void;
}
```

Meu `state` (estado):

```
const [contatoAtualizado,setContatoAtualizado]=useState<IContatos>(dados as IContatos);
```

Validação:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (dados === undefined) {
    }
    setContatoAtualizado(dados as IContatos)
}, [dados]);
```

Comment: Acredito que vc queria retornar o dados como undefined quando não houver `iContatos`, neste caso é um pipe duplo: `dados: IContatos || undefined;`

Comment: Você também pode retornar isso, ele resultará no booleano: true / false:  `return (!!IContatos);`

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer. Poderia tentar **[edit]** a pergunta para deixar mais claro qual é o seu objetivo? Você só quer atualizar o estado se `dados` for diferente de `undefined`? Nesse caso não bastaria colocar o `setContatoAtualizado(dados)` dentro do `if`, mudando-o também para `if (dados !== undefined) { ... }`?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tentar usar o operador `typeof`. Por exemplo :

```
if (typeof dados === "undefined")
```

Aparentemente sempre que for `undefined` você quer executar `setContatoAtualizado` correto? Se for isso você pode tentar usar no `useEffect` já passando essa condição, algo como:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof dados === "undefined"){
    setContatoAtualizado(dados as IContatos);
  }
}, [dados]);
```

Comment: Não creio que passar o `typeof dados === "undefined"` no array de dependências do `useEffect` seja uma boa ideia. Além de não ajudar o TypeScript a inferir a "nulidade" (se está nulo ou não) de `dados`, pode acabar criando comportamentos inesperados. Ademais, até onde sei, o array de dependências não foi feito para ser usado dessa maneira (embora, nessa última afirmação, posso estar errado).

Comment: Realmente cometi um equívoco,  o array de dependências não foi feito para esse tipo de uso, editando para apenas o uso do if dentro do useEffect.